# Is it okay to put layouts in the Views/MyController directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a layout that I would like to use for multiple pages in only one controller. I am following this guide in Pro ASP.NET 4.5

[image]

It says layouts which are not specific to a single controller belong in Views/Shared but it doesn't mention where you should put layouts that are only used by a single controller? What is the proper convention to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go in `Views\Foo` where your controller name is `FooController`. That's the convention. However, the actual location of the layout doesn't really matter, since you always must specify a reference to it either in the view or in something a little more global like `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Path/To/My/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

It should be project-relative, of course, but other than that, you could really put it any where.